# Page navigation with fixed header

Tags: html, navigation

I have a horizontal fixed header on top of my site and when I use page navigation to scroll to an ID, it puts the content I'm trying to scroll to underneath the header.

Is there a way I can offset where the page navigation shows up by 80 pixels (down)?

**Edit:** I was actually able to fix it myself in the simplest and most acceptable manner possible. I put the solution in an answer below.

Comment: are you looking something like tabbed navigation . qyestion is not clear:-(

Comment: No, page navigation. `<a href='#blabla'>Click here and it scrolls to blabla</a>` Honestly, I didn't think that could be interpreted any other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since no one else had an answer, I fixed it myself.

Here is the fix:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux2we/)

This was done by making a hidden `div` that is absolutely positoned 'x' amount of pixlels above the content I want to scroll to. I then scroll to that `div` instead of the content I originally wanted to scroll to. 'x' should be the height of your header, this way the content you want to scroll to appears directly below your header like it should.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with CSS.

#### HTML:

```
<header>Your Header Here</header>
<div id=main>Rest of Content</header>
```

#### CSS:

```
header { position: fixed; height: 80px; }
#main { margin-top: 80px; }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The main content is moved down 80 pixels, but the body still reached the top of the page, so the local links still go to the top of the page.

Comment: I believe it would have to be done in javascript or jQuery by doing something like this:  When you click on a link where the href attribute starts with a "#", then it would create an invisible element 80 pixels above that and link to that instead.

Comment: Which is why I said ALL the rest of the content should go in `#main`. Otherwise it won't work. You can also apply the `margin-top` on the `body` itself.

Comment: Neither of those will work because the header is inside the body and when you click on an on-page link, that content moves to the top of the __body__ there's now way to get to go only to the top of the #main. (It might work if you had set the positioning on the main to fixed, but just margin-top doesn't do anything to stop it from moving underneath the header) and setting the margin on the whole body won't work because the header is inside the body too.

Comment: Yes, but if the header is FIXED then it will relate not to the BODY but to the DOCUMENT, think about it :)

Comment: Okay, you were right about that then, but that doesn't fix the scrolling problem. Here, I used your example to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/VjET4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this artcle from Chris Coyier. He cleverly uses a pseudo-element to solve the "fixed header in page navigation" issue. Take a look: http://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/.

Comment: You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer and include the essential parts of the solution from that page here. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259

Answer (score 0):

The example doesn't show how it works. I fixed it by adding:

```
#header {
    opacity:0.5;
}
#content-scroller {
    height:120px;
}
```